# How to deal with a script which has shebang line in setup script?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py, shebang

I have the following structure of my distribution source:

```
|project
    |setup.py
    |project.py
    |package
        |__init__.py
        |code.py
```

`project.py` is the main script and **it has shebang line**.

Should I define somehow the above mentioned fact in `setup.py`?

Comment: You mean, `project.py` is a script that's actually supposed to be run from the command line, as opposed to an importable module?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what your question is... What do you mean by "define [this] fact in setup.py"? I don't really see the point of having the shebang there, but I also don't quite see what you're asking.

Comment: I want the user will run project.py from the command line. Thus, I set shebang line. I'd like to know whether it's necessary to write smth about project.py in setup script (maybe, using 'scripts' keyword).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the setuptools [`console_scripts` entry point](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation).

Say your `project.py` currently contains something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_proj()
```

You need to move first move `project.py` *inside* the `package` directory to be able to reference it from `setup.py`. Then, register the `run_proj` function with the `console_scripts` entry point like this:

**`setup.py`**

```
setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'run-proj = package.project:run_proj',
        ],
    }
)
```

After that, you'll need to re-run `setup.py`, for example by doing `python setup.py develop`, or whichever method you're using during development.

Then you'll get a `bin/run-proj` script that calls `run_proj()`, and can be called from the command line. (If you install the package in a virtual env, that will be in `venv/bin/run-proj`, or if you install it system-wide, somewhere like `usr/local/bin/run-proj`, depending on your OS / distro).

That script should actually be on your path, so you should be able to just run `run-proj` from the shell.

At this point, the shebang line isn't really necessary any more, and you can remove it (the `bin/run-proj` will have an automatically generated shebang pointing to the proper Python interpreter).